# Datatable pagination grays out links that are not going to be clickable

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I'm using the datatables to form my data. When the page loads it shows

> first previous 1 2 3 next last

Now the first, previous and 1 when clicked shouldn't do anything by default. How do I style these to make it show that it is grayed out. Same thing goes after you click last, how do I make it grayed out after clicking it.

Is there a Datatable setup to make these changes?

Comment: ui-state-disabled is the class that jQuery UI plugins normally use to style a disabled button. I looked it up and it appears the same with datatables. Although I've never used this plugin so I can't answer your question in detail.

Comment: BTW...checking out DataTables for the first time and I'm wondering how I've never heard of this plug-in before. It looks incredible

Answer (score 0):

> ui-state-disabled

This was the class to add rule to. Thanks.